# Can I have a static ISO8601DateFormatter with specific formatOptions in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, static

I have a `struct` that needs to do consistent date formatting, so I want my struct to have a `ISO8601DateFormatter` with `.formatOptions = .withFullDate`.

If I have a constant on the `struct` instance, it's easy enough to set `.formatOptions = .withFullDate` in `init()`.

```
struct MyStruct1 {
    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    init() {
        dateFormatter.formatOptions = .withFullDate
    }
    // Other functions go here
}
```

But if I have a static constant, then it's wrong to set `.formatOptions = .withFullDate` in `init()`, because it won't be set if I use the constant in a static function.

I tried this:

```
struct MyStruct2 {
    static let dateFormatter =
    ISO8601DateFormatter(
        formatOptions: .withFullDate
    )
    // Other functions go here
}
```

But that does not compile. I get `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to get a static `ISO8601DateFormatter` with `formatOptions=.withFullDate`?

Comment: @HangarRash yes, I think it does. Thankyou! I'll do a more detailed review and reply more fully this weekend.